# c - how to access defined values in separate header file

Tags: c, header, byte, fopen, fwrite

So I have a separate file called simulator.h with defined values such as:

```
#define PEPPERONI    1
#define CHEESE       2
#define VEGETARIAN   3
```

I have a separate csv file filled with a column of pizza topping choices. In my program called converting.c I'm trying to write a program that reads in data from the csv file and writes the data in a new file called toppings.bin with alterations. What I'm having trouble with is figuring out how to access the numeric values defined with each topping in the .h file. It should basically print a single byte with a value that depends on the type of topping defined in the .h file. So like if the csv file says 'PEPPERONI' the bin file should print '1'.

Also I'm a little confused as to how I would declare a byte variable in c and would appreciate some explanation.

For example, I have:

```
char *one = getfield(buf, 1);
char *two = getfield(buf, 2);
if(one && two && strcmp(first, "Pizzas") == 0){
  fprintf(ft, "%x \n", two);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by byte variable?  A variable which is a single byte?

Comment: I just need to write a single byte with an assigned value from the header file. I'm just a little confused on how I would write a byte exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to strcmp the string of the topping.  If it matches you fprintf(...,"%c",value).  Remember, character and byte are often synonymous in C despite what English may say about what is and isn't a "character."

ie

```
if (strcmp(one,"Pepperoni") == 0)
    fprintf(ft,"%c", PEPPERONI);
```

Comment: Hi, I have one small question: but say if it was a data type other than a character or byte - like a float. How would I get it to print a float to the .bin file? doing float *two = getfield(buf, 2); and fprintf("%f") wouldn't work would it?

Comment: %f is indeed how you print a float.  I think if you open the file in byte mode and use `fprintf(...,"%f",...);` it should come out in the file in it's binary form.  But I say this by intuition only (been years since I tried) so if it doesn't, don't quote me.

Comment: If your using a `.bin` output file, then writing to the file would use statements similar to: `write( fd, buffer, length );`  NOT any of the `printf()` family of functions as they output readable text,  not binary values.

Comment: You're right.  Could have sworn it was a little smarter than that.